# Failed to resolve firebase-ui:0.4.0

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Trying to update my firebaseui. But Why doesn't this work in my gradle file?

```
 compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.4.0'
```

**UPDATE**
Still same problem.

My other dependicies ar also updated:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'

    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'


    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.maps:google-maps-services:0.1.12'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4.3'

    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.0'


    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-simple-login:1.4.2'
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.0.0"
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.4.0'
```

Answer (score 5):

**Update:**
The bug has been fixed and the new build is already pushed. Here's the last official reply from the bug post.

> Ok I just pushed a fix for this. There will be some propagation delay.
>   If you can try it in >= 1hr and let me know if it works that
>   would be great. Just build your project with the gradle flag
>   --refresh-dependencies to make sure it re-downloads deps and does not use the cached copy.

---

`FirebaseUI` is moved to `jCenter` in `0.4.0`, thus it can't be found in `mavenCentral`. If it's still giving error, try to add Database and Auth dependencies separately, like this

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.0'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:0.4.0'
```

This has been marked as a bug already [here](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/125). You can read the bug post to read more about this issue.
Here's the official reply on the bug

> Ok I'm glad that solved your problem. For what it's worth,
>   com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.4.0 is just an empty library that
>   declares dependencies on those libraries for convenience.
>
> I will leave this issue open until I can figure out what's going on
>   with my jCenter configuration, thanks for the report!

Answer (score 2):

For some reason 0.4.0 is not avaible through bintray or mavencentral..

0.3.1 works though, so try that for now. I will look into it later.

```
'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.3.1'
```

Comment: Tried it at home didn't work either. Check this out https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android

Answer (score 0):

1. maoke sure you are using Jcenter.
2. if **compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.0'** and 
   **compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:0.4.0'**  still not work for you, try to go to **Settings-> Build,execution, Deployment ->** and disable **offline Work**