# Can't get connection to the database in signup/in activity. Firebase - 9.0.0

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

**UPDATED Description**

How can send the user to the database at the same time as a user signup. Worked in my old code but not anymore, what am I missing?

It gets connection with the database when the user is logged in and when i start my geo tagging of the user in mainActivy(). But I need it to be saved immediately when the user sigs up and gets logged in. So something with the code is wrong in my login activity.

**Login Activity:**

```
mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
        FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (user != null) {
            // User is signed in
            Log.d("TAG", "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());

            DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(); 

            // Authenticated successfully with authData
            Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            map.put("email", email);
            ref.child("users").child(user.getUid()).updateChildren(map);  


            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainReal.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);

        } else {
            // User is signed out
            Log.d("TAG", "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
        }
    }
};
```

**Dependencies**

```
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.0.0"
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.0'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.0'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:0.4.0'
```

[image]

Comment: Do any database calls work? Can you should how you are creating the ref variable?

Comment: Ah, that's the old way! The new SDK is the "after" box on that same page. I am somewhat surprised that one was compiling! Do you have dependencies on the old SDK as well as the new one?

Comment: Yes I've the new ones look updated question

Comment: Did you update how you got your reference? Also you have firebaseui-0.3.1 in there - you can remove that (as you have 0.4.0) which should remove the old SDK as well!

Comment: Thats the problem, its some kind of bug, check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37349109/failed-to-resolve-firebase-ui0-4-0/37355118#37355118

Comment: That should be fixed now, try again!

Comment: Didn't work, still same problem. Updated a debug picture. It should work but doesn't

Comment: It gets connection with the database when the user is logged in and when i start my geo tagging of the user. But I need it to be saved immediately when the user sigs up and gets logged in. So something with the code is wrong in my login activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that `String email` is `null`

**The following solved the problem**

```
map.put("email", user.getEmail());
```