# minSdkVersion 21 crashes app. 20 and below works fine

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library

Currently my app `minSdkVersion 15`. Everything works great. With what I want to add to my app, I need `multidex` or `minSdkVersion 21` or higher. Either way I try, my app crashes giving me this error.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzab;
 04-04 13:14:09.612 20274 20274 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.zza(Unknown Source:2)
 04-04 13:14:09.612 20274 20274 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source:0)
 04-04 13:14:09.612 20274 20274 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6572)
 04-04 13:14:09.612 20274 20274 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6127)
 04-04 13:14:09.612 20274 20274 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6037)
 04-04 13:14:09.612 20274 20274 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
 04-04 13:14:09.612 20274 20274 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1764)
 04-04 13:14:09.612 20274 20274 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
 04-04 13:14:09.612 20274 20274 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
 04-04 13:14:09.612 20274 20274 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
 04-04 13:14:09.612 20274 20274 E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 04-04 13:14:09.612 20274 20274 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
 04-04 13:14:09.612 20274 20274 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
 04-04 13:14:09.612 20274 20274 E   AndroidRuntime                               Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzab" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.JEB.trailmaps-USsJPJClgRBZb0OXtU0Gmg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.JEB.trailmaps-USsJPJClgRBZb0OXtU0Gmg==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.JEB.trailmaps-USsJPJClgRBZb0OXtU0Gmg==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
 04-04 13:14:09.612 20274 20274 E   AndroidRuntime                               at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
 04-04 13:14:09.612 20274 20274 E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
 04-04 13:14:09.612 20274 20274 E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
```

I get that without even adding anymore dependencies.  All I do is change `minSdkVersion` to 21. Everything I've found thru Google points to needing multidex. But I haven't actually added anymore dependencies to actually need multidex yet. I get that same log when I add multidex too.

**Here's my Gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 24
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.JEB.trailmaps"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 533
        versionName "5.3.3"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:5.5.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.0'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.4.0'
        compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.0'
        compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.4.0"
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.4.0'
    }
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: I guess the functionality your trying to perform is possibly deprecated in SDK 21 or higher !

Comment: try updating all your libraries, compileSdk and buildtools version

Comment: When trying to use latest play- services places I get "Dependency com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:12.0.1 not found".  Idk if I should've mentioned before that I'm using AIDE app to make my app on my phone so I can work on it at work on my down time.

Comment: Also get the same not found error for ads when I change that to latest lib

Answer (score 2):

I noticed few things:

- Your dependencies show `25.0.0` while your `compileSdkVersion and
  targetSdkVersion is 24`
- Assuming that you have added rules to your root-level `build.gradle` file, to include the google-services plugin and the [Google's Maven repository](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup)

---

```
buildscript {
    // ...
    dependencies {
        // ...
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0' // google-services plugin
    }
}

allprojects {
    // ...
    repositories {
        // ...
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
        }
    }
}
```

- If you are using `build:gradle:3.0 or higher` [please use](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#new_configurations) `implementation` instead of `compile`
- If you have `firebase dependencies`, always make sure to update their version to [match version](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) of `google services`
- **Recommended:** Download the latest Google Support Repository (at-least 26.0.0 or higher if you are working with firebase and Google Services) - you can find it in `Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager -> SDK Tools`
- Failed to resolve `com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.0` read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37349109/failed-to-resolve-firebase-ui0-4-0/37355118#37355118)

So, your final Gradle file should look something like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.JEB.trailmaps"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 533
        versionName "5.3.3"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jCenter()
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:5.5.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:12.0.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:12.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:12.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```